# Body parameters in Blazemeter

Tags: testing, blazemeter

I'm importing test with OAS in blazemeter but I'm having the problem that in the POST methods the body parameters are not set, instead it puts an uninitialised variable.

Is there any solution for this or BM does not support this behaviour?

Comment: Help others help you better. 1. Expand abbreviations 2. Provide code snippets of the received vs expected body. 3. How have you configured it? Show some config or code. 4. Describe what you are doing in a bit more detail.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.